# CSS: удалить lablel при событии :focus

Tags: html, css

```css
input {
  padding: 5px 15px;
}

label:focus {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<label>Имя*</label>
<input type="text">
```

Каким образом можно удалить `label` при фокусе на `input`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Предлагаю автору как вариант, если JS использовать нельзя `<input type="text" placeholder="Имя*">`
Если с JS, то:

```js
let input = document.querySelector('#name');
let label = document.querySelector('label[for="name"]');
input.addEventListener('focus', () => {
  label.style.visibility = 'hidden';
});
input.addEventListener('blur', () => {
  label.style.visibility = 'visible';
});
```

```html
<label for="name">Имя*</label>
<input id="name" type="text">
```

Answer (score 2):

Обманите всех с порядком следования элементов:

```css
.wrap {
  display: flex;
}

input {
  padding: 5px 15px;
}

label {
  order: -1;
  padding-right: 15px;
}

input:focus + label {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <input id="id-1" type="text">
  <label for="id-1">Имя*</label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

К сожалению нельзя в css обращаться к предыдущему элементу, НО можно к следующему. если поменять их местами в css то будет выглядеть как у вас, но я для простоты поменял их местами в коде:

```css
input {
  padding: 5px 15px;
}

input:focus + label {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<input type="text">
<label>Имя*</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

Возможности менять местами `lable` и `input` нет, поэтому решение было следующим:

```
input {
z-index: 1;
position: relative;
background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .4);//полу-прозрачный белый
}

input:focus {
background-color: #faffbd;//бледно-желтый
}

lable {
position: relative;
z-index: 0;
background: #fff;//белый
display: block;
}
```

Lable c помощью `top: 26px;` был размещен сверху `input`, но так как у `lable` задан `z-index: 0;`, а у `input z-index: 1`, то `lable` скрыт под `input`, но т.к. `input` имеет прозрачный фон, то `label` просвечивается. При фокусе `input` меняем бекграунд с полу-прозрачного белого, на бледно-желтый не прозрачный.

В результате:

По умолчанию

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При фокусе
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]